# Figure inside leftbar environment generates error "Not in outer par mode"

Tags: floats, errors, framed

> ! LaTeX Error: Not in outer par
>   mode.

I seek a solution to be able to make this figure inside leftbar environment work:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{framed}

\begin{document}

\begin{leftbar}

\begin{figure}[h!]
  \caption{Mean data points enclosed by shapes are contained within the same group, within 95\% confidence.}
\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{"../Data Analysis Files/InteractionPlotforTransLog10(X+1)Count"}
\end{figure}

\end{leftbar}


\end{document}
```

@Stefan Kottwitz, your solution is otherwise perfect, but it does introduce this problem of cropping at the end of pages:

[image]

Comment: What output are you expecting? The `figure` environment is a float, which seems inappropriate in a side bar.

Comment: I use the bar to distinguish certain sections of text as responses, while the rest of the text unaccompanied by the leftbar are questions.  It's an article with a Q&A format, each time an answer is offered the leftbar is inserted.

Comment: It's being used as a fancy quotation environment if you like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use leftbar inside the figure environment. By changin the nesting you still can let it float. If you don't need floating, you don't need a figure environment: captions can be done then using the caption package (or capt-of).

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
   \begin{leftbar}
    \caption{Mean data points enclosed by shapes are contained within the same group, within 95\% confidence.}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{"../Data Analysis Files/InteractionPlotforTransLog10(X+1)Count"}
  \end{leftbar}
\end{figure}
```

A solution without `figure`, so you can put this and everything else into an outer `leftbar` environment:

```
\usepackage{caption}
...
\begin{leftbar}
\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
  \captionof{figure}{Mean data points enclosed by shapes are contained within the same group, within 95\% confidence.}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{"../Data Analysis Files/InteractionPlotforTransLog10(X+1)Count"}
\end{minipage}
```

Comment: Sorry, I should've made it clearer there are other text, figures and tables contained within leftbar as well - I omitted them because this was a minimal example.  So that doesn't appear to be an option for me...  Any other ideas Stef, or others?

Comment: @ptrcao: I added an example without `figure` but with caption.

Comment: Nice - it works! Solution accepted, with thanks.  :)

Comment: It was important to create a minipage environment - which you recognised - because otherwise the caption and graphic don't stay together as a coherent unit, so nicely constructed Stef :)

Comment: or anyone else reading this - Can you please have a look at the unwanted cropping depicted in my OP (applies to Stefan's solution immediately preceding) and suggest, if you know a way to control this issue?